# my very first php exercise puts '000' on the screen - what is going on?

Tags: php

My code is below.
I set up XAMP, and whatever non-php stuff I type in the html file prints out just fine.
But where is the '000' coming from?
Looks vaguely like some UNIX permissions but again, what is going on?
my [lessons](http://www.killerphp.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php/) mention nothing like this. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>OOP in PHP</title>

    <?php include("class_lib.php"); ?>
</head>

<body>

    <?php
        $stefan = new person();
        $jimmy = new person();

        $stefan->set_name('Stefan Mischook');
        $jimmy->set_name('Nick Waddles');

        echo "Stefan's full name: " + $stefan->get_name();
        echo "Nick's full name: " + $jimmy->get_name();
     ?>

</body>

</html>
```

and this...

```
<?php 

    class person {
        var $name;

        function __construct($persons_name) {
            $this->name = $persons_name;
        }

        function set_name($new_name) {
            $this->name = $new_name;
        }

        function get_name() {
            return $this->name;
        }
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: Use `.` for concatenating strings

Comment: Mate. Read the documentation for the things you use.

Comment: For a beginner this is very well written however. Not the usual cobweb of crap you see every day.

Comment: @wesley and yet I'm more than willing to help close this as a typo question.

Comment: Close this question, and no one will see that php doesn't follow the concatenation syntax a beginner would expect. If I had cut and pasted the code then I would not have had this lesson. Much thx to the real answers below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.` for concatenating strings

```
echo "Stefan's full name: " . $stefan->get_name();
echo "Nick's full name: " . $jimmy->get_name();
```

Answer (score 1):

`+` is additon: `0 + 0 = 0`.  You wan't to concatenate.  In PHP use `.`:

```
echo "Stefan's full name: " . $stefan->get_name();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    echo "Nick's full name: " + $jimmy->get_name();
                              ^---- mathematical addition
```

You're trying to add two strings as if they were numbers. You want `.`, for concatenation.